# Callback inside a useState updater function in react Hooks

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

Im new to hook and so is react,Ive been watching some tutorials lately,I saw [Ben awad's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GtAE9RZHVc) for dynamic forms and I tried replicating it.There he used a callback inside the useState updater function which seems new to me.He used link `setPeople(currentPeople => {})` What is the argument `currentPeople` come from and why its used,Can you someone please explain,Thanks in advance!

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { generate } from "shortid";
interface Person {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState<Person[]>([
    {
      id: "5",
      firstName: "Aashiq",
      lastName: "Ahmed",
    },
  ]);
  return (
    <>
      <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Dynamic Form </h2>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setPeople((currentPeople) => [
              ...currentPeople,
              {
                id: generate(),
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
              },
            ]);
          }}
        >
          add new person
        </button>
        {people.map((p, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={p.id}>
              <input
                placeholder="first name"
                value={p.firstName}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const firstName = e.target.value;
                  setPeople((
                    currentPeople 
                  ) =>
                    currentPeople.map((x) =>
                      x.id === p.id ? { ...x, firstName } : x
                    )
                  );
                }}
              />
              <input
                placeholder="last name"
                value={p.lastName}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const lastName = e.target.value;
                  setPeople((currentPeople) =>
                    currentPeople.map((x) =>
                      x.id === p.id ? { ...x,lastName } : x
                    )
                  );
                }}
              />
            <button onClick={()=> setPeople( currentPeople =>currentPeople.filter(x=> x.id !== p.id) )}>x</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div>
          
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(people,  null,  3)}</pre>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No better explanation than the official one.
Here is the link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

Your `currentPeople` is what the variable name suggests, the current value of the
`const [people, setPeople] = useState<Person[]`
For example:
You might send only one person that you want to add to your people's array, so you end up just attaching that Person to an already existing array of Persons.
Sure you could use `setPeople([...people, newPerson])` but this wouldn't be correct in 100% of places because `people` might not have the latest value so the callback function comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

It is the current value of that state, this might come in handy, when you want to use the previous state to calculate the next state. An example would be a toggle function, that would toggle a modal or sth.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const toggleIsOpen = () => setIsOpen(open=>!open);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be setIsOpen(open=>!open) ?

Comment: my bad @Hugo fixed