# empty arrow function inside useState in react

Tags: reactjs, use-state

why some people use an empty arrow function in useState like this `const [email, setEmail] = useState(() => {})`?

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Check this post for the explanation about useState callback function:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263694/callback-inside-a-usestate-updater-function-in-react-hooks/65263806#65263806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are setting the email to an  object which its value will later be set using another function. Try read more about Hooks [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: The more you practice, the more you understand. So try logging out your result to the console to understand faster

Comment: Why doesn't the code say `const [email, setEmail] = useState({})` then? Doesn't that do the same thing, only more explicitly. Is there some advantage to using a function in the useState hook. I'm guessing that it provides some kind of closure to the actual object, so that we can use the `setEmail` fn differently. Am I wrong?